# How to view apps packageName with ADB commands?

Tags: adb

For some reasons, I want to find out the packageName from APK files in my pc (Without installing the app on the device. 
I use adb commands such as adb install or adb devices and etc..

Is it a simple way to find out the packageName with command prompt?

Comment: If your intention is to get package name without installing apk and from the apk file means , Yes you can use `aapt dump badging  xxx.apk`

Comment: I was looking for code with adb command, this is why I make a new question. because I have a problem with aapt.exe (explained here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52611057/whu-does-the-aapt-exe-command-doesnt-recognize-the-grep)  anyway thank you